# How can I extend the Forms Authentication time in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication, timeout

When I post something on my ASP.Net website,
the sessions on page are become null if been waited 7 minute and 10 seconds.

I have this on Global.asax's onSessionStart method

```
Session.Timeout= 60;
```

And have this code in web.config but any of it does not work :

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None">
    <forms timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" />
  </authentication>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is belong to server's session idle time.
I have changed it in Application Pools.

To do this :
Control Panel/
Administrative Tools/
Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager/
on the left : Application Pools
right click and select Advanced Settings/
IIS Time-out...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the authentication is working, since it is set to none.

It should be set to Forms. ie

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
```

Comment: Hm ok but I set it to None because I don't use the Membership